# where are the variable stored that are initialized in main function in c?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

In C language, I know that when a variable is dynamically initialized using malloc, it is stored in heap area. But where is the memory allocated when declaration of below kind is done and variables are initialized later.

`int a[26];`

or

```
int a[n]; //n is a variable and each element in array a is later initialized through a for loop.
```

My initial understanding is that like in java, here also all variables declared in main function are stored in stack area. My doubt is- Say, there is a function that takes the address of array "a" and changes its contents. To change the contents of "a", it should be able to access each element's address in "a". As the function itself is getting executed in the stack space on the top of main function, it cannot access array "a"'s contents directly. So, my doubt is where is array "a"'s memory allocated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, `int a[n];` is called a variable length array, and the storage allocation is compiler dependent.

For example, [`gcc` allocates VLAs in stack memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

FWIW, the local variables are also usually stored in stack memory (minus the compiler optimization, if any).

Comment: Let's say a function, void fun(int a[]){ a[0]=1;}.
int main(){ int a[5]={0}; fun(&a);}
Now, to change a[0], fun should know the address of a and it is in stack area. when fun is called it is created on the top of main function's stack area right, so, how can fun access a[0] directly is my question

Comment: @anil first of all, you should call it like `fun(a);`, and then, you're passing the array, right? It will decay to the pointer to the first elemnt of the array, so you have the address. What seems to be the issue?

Comment: it looks clear now, when i pass "a" as argument, the function created in the stack will keep a pointer to "a" residinf in main memory. understood. thanks.

Comment: One question though- say a variable a is located at 1234 address on stack.Later, lot of variables were pushed into stacka nd now the top of stack pointer is at 1002. Now, can we directly access variable "a" as we know the memory location. i.e. Can we do direct memory access on stack or only access is not possible untill top of stack reaches address 1234?

Comment: @anil It has not to do much with the top or whatever, if you know the address and it is a valid access, you're good to go.

Comment: A basic question- All the functions are executed in stack space right, the same applies for main() function also right?First, main() is pushed and then function after function when they are called?

Answer (score -1):

arrays can be almost any length, they can be used to store thousands or even millions of objects, but the size must be decided when the array is created. Each item in the array is accessed by an index, which is just a number that indicates the position or slot where the object is stored in the array.

Array size stored in the computer physical memory

Comment: The poster is asking where in the process' memory specific variable declarations are stored, not what an array is or which hardware data device it is stored to. I think it's safe to assume that he knows data is stored in physical memory.